# How to run existing rails project in netbeans

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, netbeans

I imported a rails application into netbeans, but I don't know how to run it. Any suggestions please. It has folders such as `Models`, `Views`, `Configuration`, `Libs`, `Logs`, `Scripts` etc. Need to know from where I can run it.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please see the [Stack Overflow Newbie Manual](http://grahn.us/projects/stack-overflow.php). It will help you get better answers to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is still to run it from the command line.

Open your terminal, navigate to the project directory, and run:

```
rails s
```

This will start a server and you may access your project at:

```
http://localhost:3000
```

See this article on the [Rails Command Line](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html).

Comment: By appropriate directory you mean the project directory or any sub directories inside it ?

Comment: when i typed `rails s` in the console am getting the following thing
`Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]`

Comment: What version of rails are you using?

Comment: @user94962 Go ahead and jump on the rails chat room. I'll try to help you there.

Comment: I have joined the chat .

Comment: Go to rails application folder then try to run. rails s